# Gmail offline mode

Tags: offline

I'm connected to my network and Wi-Fi is on but I cannot search in google nor can I send email.  It says that gmail is offline.  How do I change this?
I'm using a ProScan Android tablet.

Answer (score 0):

Just because you are connected to WiFi does not mean you are online.

1. Try browsing using your built in browser. If you can then post it.
2. If you can't, then check if you can browse in other devices connected to the same WiFi network.
3. If you can't, then try running diagnostics in your router. This will show if your router can connect to your ISP. To do this, you have to open router settings in a web browser. Check your router manual for more info on this.

Please post the result from all the abide tests.

Answer (score -1):

which android do you have ? what version of gmail do you have. Tell in detail that what your gmail is actually telling. Do you had forced closed it? if force closed, then try clearing its data and later do everything that you have done in the first time.